# Delay() issue in C

Tags: c, winapi, wait

Even though I set different `Sleep()` timer for each print statement, it seems to only do the one with the highest timer. Need some help fixing this. TIA!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(short int x, short int y);

int main()
{
    int c = 1, d = 1, e, x, y, z, a;
    srand ( time(NULL) );

    for(a = 0; a <= 100; a++) {
        x = rand() % 9 + 1;
        y = rand() % 9 + 1;
        z = rand() % 9 + 1;
        gotoxy(5, 5); 
        Sleep(200); printf("%i", x);
        gotoxy(8, 5); 
        Sleep(50); printf("%i", y);
        gotoxy(11, 5); 
        Sleep(500); printf("%i", z);
   }

   return 0;
}

void gotoxy(short int x, short int y){
    COORD pos = {x, y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
}
```

Comment: I think you just don't notice it, because the time is in milliseconds? (Just add a 0 to ever value of sleep and maybe then you can tell the difference)

Comment: I don't know how it works with gotoxy, but remember that the standard output is line buffered, so perhaps your printf output doesn't show up because it isn't flushed to screen until at the end?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to smoothly print the y & z fast with just the x to slow down in printing but I can't figure how to do it.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: that depends on the compiler.  IIRC, Visual Studio (and hence MinGW) doesn't do line buffering, standard output is unbuffered (if sent to a console window) or fully buffered (if redirected to a file or pipe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't expect too much accuracy from application-level `sleep()` - like implementation. Usually their timers can easily miss 10-s of milliseconds.
2. In accordance to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) this `Sleep()` parameter is in milliseconds. So it is easy just to not notice such pauses. Especially having not so accurate implementation.

My recommendation is just to multiply time intervals and check. Or log current wall clock time.

Comment: Sir, can you show me a simple example of multiplying time intervals as a delay?

Comment: You had intervals like 50 ms which is 0.05 second. How do you expect to note such interval? Just add 0 to them, for example: 2000, 500, 5000 -> 2s, 0.5s, 5s will be enough to note.

Comment: Please be aware, user (application) level timers are inaccurate. This is root cause of many issues where programmers did not pay attention.